# Bash wrong date formatting at Team City

Tags: bash, teamcity

Getting date locally by

```
DATE=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
```

works fine, but at Team City the same script returns 1m13. I think, because of 13/08/18. Any ideas will be helpful.

Comment: I can't think of any circumstances under which `date +%Y-%m-%d` would output `1m13`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have found a solution. TeamCity uses percent signs for its properties. So to use % in TeamCity we should escape it with other %, i.e. for % it must be %%.

Comment: That's great that you found the answer to your problem @alexdrob, you should now accept your own answer as the answer to the question.